# Is it necessary to use coordinator layout as the first child of drawer layout

Tags: android

In the navigation drawer implementation they use coordinator layout as first child of drawer layout

Is it necessary to use it ?

I use linear layout and it work wells

What is the reason behind to use coordinator layout ?

Comment: Its not necessary . If you want to apply some fancy behavior during scrolling then you can use coordinator layout. Read [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30536749/what-is-coordinatorlayout).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is CoordinatorLayout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30536749/what-is-coordinatorlayout)